# Historical Data on $/yen forward exchange rates

Tags: data, fx, futures

Would anyone happen to know where I can find historical forward exchange rate data between the yen and dollar?

Comment: Would that be the same thing as a currency future?

Comment: yeah, I am looking for same thing but eur/usd. I could find 30 min timeframe but I need like minutes. whoever share information gets my point too :)

Comment: Yes, I believe currency futures and forward exchange rates are the same thing.

Comment: You might get in trouble if you believe that.  http://www.investopedia.com/terms/c/currencyforward.asp

Comment: While futures and forwards prices for the same date should be fairly close, they will not be the same generally for a number of reasons.  Also, forward prices will tend to have more dates of data so can be more useful for quantitative analysis.

Answer (score 1):

Actually for the forward rates you would need to subscribe to a financial datafeed like Bloomberg, Thomson Reuters Datastream or Interactive Data.

For the current forward rates you could look it up at here http://www.fxstreet.com/rates-charts/forward-rates/?id=usd%2fjpy, the data are provided by Interactive Data.

Answer (score 0):

You can export it here from [QUANDL](https://www.quandl.com/c/futures/cme-japanese-yen-futures) which also has an [R package](https://www.quandl.com/help/r). I don't have too much experience with it but I guess you have to open a (free) account.